# Data shows only as zeros on chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2000

I have an excel sheet with data in it:
[image]

That drives a chart, but the chart only shows 0 as data:
[image]

Each of my cell is a formula.

I tried to write a value in a cell and it shows in the chart

I tried to copy the data and paste values, but it doesn't show on the chart.

Please help.

Comment: I solved my issue by using a macro instead of a formula

Answer (score 8):

You didn't share the formula, except for very tiny in the screen shot of the formula bar. From the bits I can see (text operators "RIGHT" and "LEFT"), I can tell that it is returning text, that is numbers stored as text. Excel charts text as zeros.

Change the formula to

=VALUE(your current formula here without the equals sign)

To make sure you don't store numbers as text, you should never center align your numerical cells. Keep the default formatting. Numbers are right-adjusted, text is left-adjusted. You can detect a problem instantly.

Comment: +1 even though I strongly disagree about "never" changing the alignment. You should set the alignment to whatever makes the data easier to visualize. Though I agree you should know the difference between text and numbers before doing so.

Comment: The source data for a chart is not what you should be using to visualize tabular data. So keep the chart source data in the default horizontal alignment. For the viewable tabular data, link to the source data, but apply whatever alignment and formatting enhances the table.